# Does the distributive property apply to regular expressions?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

Let $(Q,\Sigma,\delta, q_0, F)$ be a finite automaton, does 
$$
(q_1a+q_2b)c=q_1ac+q_2bc
$$

hold for any $q_1,q_2\in Q$ and $a,b,c\in \Sigma$?

Here $Sa=\{\delta(q, a)\mid q\in S\}$ and $qa=\{q\}a$ for any $S\subseteq Q$, $q\in Q$ and $a\in\Sigma$. The operation "$+$" means set union.

Answer (score 2):

since someone has edited the question, the question seems much more meaningful , and yes the above equality holds , here the equations

taking LHS of the equation

= ( $q_1$a  $+$ $q_2$b ) c

=$\delta$ ( (   $q_1$a  $+$ $q_2$b ) , c )  { as you defined Sa={ δ (q,a) ∣q ∈ S} }

=$\delta$ ( (   $q_1$a )  $\bigcup$   $q_2$b ) , c )

=$\delta$ ( ( $q_1$a),c ))    $\bigcup$   $\delta$ ( (    $q_2$b ) , c )

=$q_1$ ac $+$ $q_2$bc

which is equal to RHS.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others your regular expression is wrong until you did not correct your definition of $q_1$ and $q_2$ to some input alphabets also i assume the same for a,b and c . If you correct this then your regular expression would make sense.

You first have to understand that a Regular expression is not an equation you can form from whatever (as you did by combining states and input alphabets) because regular expression denotes a "Set" in formal terms a "regular set". So any regular expression like "a + b" denotes regular set containing {a,b} as its elements .

Secondly there are specific rules to form the regular expression which accompany primitive regular expression and the operation you can define on them. Primitive are :

1. an input alphabet like "a" is a regex , in regular set it is {a}
2. an empty string "$\epsilon$" is a regex , in regular set it is {$\epsilon$}
3. a set that have no string that is "$\varphi$ ", in regular set it is empty set { }

Operation the above regular expression are : 1. union ( denoted by "+") , like " a + b " means {a ,b}

2.concatenation denoted by ( . ) , like "a . b" or simply "ab" means { ab }

3. kleene star closure of any of a regex like "$a^*$", denotes { $\epsilon$, a, aa,aaa.....} ,also you can add an modified version of it which we say positive star closure like "$a^+$" denoting set { a, aa, aaa,aaaa,....}

so any regular expression violating above definition is not defined like "a+b+" does not convey anything . similary you are using $q_1" as state in regex  so it is not correct regular expression .

further i request you to look again your question and then ask again.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation holds. Actually, more generally, for every subsets $S_1$, $S_2$ of $Q$ and for every words $u$, $v$ and $w$, the following equality  holds
$$
  (S_1u + S_2v)w = S_1uw + S_2vw
$$
Indeed, 
\begin{align}
  S_1u &= \{ p \in Q \mid \text{there is a path of the form $s_1 \xrightarrow{u} p$ for some state $s_1 \in S_1$} \}  \\
  S_2v &= \{ p \in Q \mid \text{there is a path of the form $s_2 \xrightarrow{v} p$ for some state $s_2 \in S_2$} \} \\
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
  (S_1u + S_2v)w &= \{ q \in Q \mid \text{there is a path of the form $p \xrightarrow{w} q$ for some state $p \in S_1u + S_2v$}\}\\
&= \{ q \in Q \mid \text{there is a path of the form $s_1 \xrightarrow{u} p \xrightarrow{w} q$ }\\
&\qquad\qquad\quad \text{for some state $s_1 \in S_1$ and some state $p \in Q$}\} + {}\\
&\phantom{{}={}} \{ q \in Q \mid \text{there is a path of the form $s_2 \xrightarrow{v} p \xrightarrow{w} q$ }\\
&\qquad\qquad\quad \text{for some state $s_2 \in S_2$ and some state $p \in Q$}\}\\
&= \{ q \in Q \mid \text{there is a path of the form $s_1 \xrightarrow{uw} q$ for some state $s_1 \in S_1$}\} + {}\\
&\phantom{{}={}} \{ q \in Q \mid \text{there is a path of the form $s_2 \xrightarrow{vw} q$ for some state $s_2 \in S_2$}\}\\
  &= S_1uw + S_2vw
\end{align}
This is actually a good reason to prefer this algebraic notation to the $\delta$ notation.